# Bluestacks: Where are my apps?

Tags: bluestacks

I am using the new Bluestacks 0.8.7 build 3069 and the home screen only loads the searching for channels and lots of apps that can be downloaded are shown. I also downloaded the MultiTool 1.06r and rooted with it. After it I installed many apps from the MultiTool one by one and they installed perfectly and could be open by the notification in the task bar. But then I restarted BS and then opened the all apps option but there weren't any apps. Where are my installed apps, though they show up in the apps section in the settings menu.

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom launcher to see all of your apps. A launcher is what displays your home screen and everything on it.

Method 1 (recommended):

1. Go to the Play Store, and search "launcher"
2. Pick one you like, and download it (I recommend Nova)
3. When you press home, it will ask you to select an app. Choose Nova Launcher, then click always.
4. To see all of the apps, click the icon that looks something like this:

[image: App Drawer Icon]

Method 2:

1. Search Google, "android launcher apk"
2. Choose from any of them, and open the link.
3. Click download. Be careful, sometimes there are advertisements that look like a download button
4. It will start downloading. To see the progress, open the notifications
5. When it is done, click on the notification
6. A screen comes up that tells you the details of the app and it's permissions. Click install
7. When it is done, press the home button
8. It will ask you to select an app. Choose Nova Launcher, then click always.
9. To see all of the apps, click the icon that looks something like the icon above

Answer (score 0):

I have owned bluestacks before, so I suggest to install a launcher like Go, Nova, Apex.

So in order to do this,

- 1st step: Go to Google Play thru downloading app (Click on any
  downloadable app then choose google play)
- 2nd step: Search "Go Launcher" (or Nova, apex)
- 3rd step: Install it
- 4th step: Press home button and choose Go Launcher or launcher you
  chose.
- 5th step: App drawer has your apps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to install any launcher. Simply open the Bluestacks and the apps will be shown in the first row and there will be a `+` symbol at the end the row. Click the plus (`+`) symbol to reveal the list of apps.

Install a launcher for better browsing of apps and press the home button to reveal the apps.